# Define type based on value of keys in an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I am adding one Select component that has the following structure.

```
type Option = {
  value: string | number
  label: string;
  icon?: string
}
type SelectProps = {
  labelKey?: string;
  iconKey?: string;
  valueKe?: string;
  options: Option[]
}

function Select({
  labelKey = 'label',
  iconKey = 'icon',
  valueKey= 'value',
  groupBy = 'groupBy',
  options// need to type Option
}: SelectProps) {
  // some logic to render options
  // options.map(option => (<li key={option[valueKey]}>{option[labelKey]}</li>))
}
```

Here, `options` is an array of options and I am trying to give flexibility to users to provide keys to use for labels, icons etc so the user doesn't need to map data all the time.

For now, the `Option` type has hardcode keys like `label`, `value`, `icon` but I want to create this type based on values passed to `labelKey`, `valueKey`, `iconKey` etc.
For example, if a user passes the `labelKey="name"` prop then the `Option` type should allow the following data:

```
[ { 
  name: 'Product',
  value: 'product',
  icon: 'product'
}]
```

So far I have tried the following implementation but it sets all keys' types to string.

```
type OptionKeys = {labelKey: string, valueKey: string, iconKey: string}
type Option<T extends OptionKeys> = {
    [label in T["labelKey" | "valueKey" | "iconKey"]]: string // all the types are string
}

type SelectProps<T extends OptionKeys = {
    labelKey: 'label',
    valueKey: 'value',
    iconKey: 'icon'
}> = {
    labelKey?: string
    valueKey?: string;
    iconKey?: string;
    options: Option<T>[]
}
```

Here, the `Option`'s keys have value of type `string` but I want to define type based on key. For example, if the key is `labelKey`, I want its value to be `number | string` etc.

One option, I see here is to accept OptionType from outside by making the Select component generic but in that case, I need to refactor my component and want to avoid this refactoring at the moment.

How can I update my type to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `FromEntries` type from this blog post: https://dev.to/svehla/typescript-object-fromentries-389c,

Define the `SelectProps` type as follows:

```
type SelectProps<LK, VK, IK> = {
    labelKey?: LK
    valueKey?: VK
    iconKey?: IK
    options: FromEntries<[
        [LK, string], 
        [VK, string | number], 
        [IK, string | undefined]
    ]>
}
```

We have three keys in the options, the label key (`LK`) which is a `string`, the value key (`VK`) which is a `string | number` and the icon key (`IK`) which is a `string | undefined`

Now we define the `Select` function as follows:

```
function Select<
    LK extends string = 'label', 
    VK extends string = 'value', 
    IK extends string = 'icon'
>(props: SelectProps<LK, VK, IK>) {}
```

It is important to put the default key names on the function itself rather than the `SelectProps` type. I am not sure why.

[**Full playground link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAogGwgWwgO2AHhiggA9hcATAZyjgkQoHsc0QpEcQBtAXQD4oAXljEylGnQbNWUABQBLHADMIcKABUAlLygB+DQC4oOCADdVAKFCQoAYURVg6xgGkIIQgOFFS5HNShHOEUAcz0RIyDQiytwaAAxOEZMFDxgiCp8dS8NUT8ArkUVNTcQABp2Th5eCyhwgG8oLhcoRTsHJ1d3fFK+HiMUMiQAYwJ4JFQMbDwsvgrmio4Qfi4ARh4oAF9aqCNGrgBrd1acQOBgnBD+yrZtmOtoAGUIDFGABSSwTIAZFwqANT+UAAki4cvUdnU0IgAEYvUq6Iy-SFQUyINAAVwgCKMgJR8mGzBxIJcKMYYGA8mYVCMiWSqXO8gy+C4KLqdS4vwqUUuPAqbPZXEB3MZlygAB9jBjMHC4HyoAKOaCRRcwpKMf4IEpFBAKDwUfwLHclBrRlTTs9XgQUb88uIzqqhFAAOTQuFoZ389lQQF2-w0HlhYTOtGYiCehXe0F+gKBp3OgnMZ0WPiyMCfGlQS0Qd4Z-Bcn1A0F8TRQerbIA)